# Font Awesome not aligining properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

[image: screenshot of issue]

I can't seem to get the font awesome icons to load properly. The page in question can be found here: http://thelink.biz/AboutUs/

Am I loading the font awesome correctly or is there a conflict with Bootstrap?

Comment: the page looks ok, just ok, but not great to me, what is your specific problem - what do you expect to happen and what is actually occurring?

Comment: I'm expecting unicorns to appear!

Comment: Occasionally you have to tweak a CSS framework, including Bootstrap, to get the desired look on a site. In this case added padding is needed on the `<a>` tag..

Comment: I'm confused because it's working here: http://www.thelink.biz/business/listing/Embroidery-Plus/59.html

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct styling (`line-height: 30px` in `stylesheet.css` applying to the icons using `.social-links > li a`), but the order that you are loading the stylesheets in the page means that it is getting overridden by the default font awesome style. Make sure that you load `stylesheet.css` *after* the font awesome css files in your header.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you placed google analytics code wrogly at the top of the html file. Please place the code at the bottom of the html file & of course inside body tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tags need some padding to push down the FontAwesome icons.

I was able to add

```
padding-top:7px
```

to the `<a>` and it fixed the centering of the icons.